# Problema con login

Tags: php, mysqli, login

Estoy intentando hacer un login con una base de datos y PHP, lo cual logré avances y pareciera que funciona, pero me deja entrar con cualquier nombre y contraseña.

Configuré el PHP del server en 5.6 y creo que el problema es por usar `mysql_real_escape_string` en vez de `mysqli_real_escape_string` dado que en los tutoriales del trabajo que hice utilizo `$mysqli = new mysqli(...)` para conectar.

¿Me podrían guiar para pasar lo que hice a `mysqli_real_escape_string`?

**login.php**

```
    <?php
session_start();

  // Obtengo los datos cargados en el formulario de login.
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
// // Datos para conectar a la base de datos.
   $nombreServidor =3333333 ;
   $nombreUsuario = 3333333;
   $passwordBaseDeDatos =3333333 ;
   $nombreBaBaseDeDatos=3333333;

  // // Crear conexión con la base de datos.
   $conn = new mysqli($nombreServidor, $nombreUsuario, $passwordBaseDeDatos, $nombreBaseDeDatos);

  // // Validar la conexión de base de datos.
   if ($conn ->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn ->connect_error);
  }


  // Consulta segura para evitar inyecciones SQL.
  $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre ='%s' AND password ='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($nombre), mysql_real_escape_string($password));
  $resultado = $conn->query($sql);

  // Verificando si el usuario existe en la base de datos.
  if($resultado){
    // Guardo en la sesión el email del usuario.
    $_SESSION['nombre'] = $nombre;

    // Redirecciono al usuario a la página principal del sitio.
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily");
    header("Location: principal.php");
  }else{
    echo 'El usuario o password es incorrecto, <a href="index.html">vuelva a intenarlo</a>.<br/>';
  }

?>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Control Service Robert</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="publica/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="publica/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="publica/estilos3.css">
      <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="publica/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header" class="">
        <h1>Control Service Robert</h1>
    </header>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="imagen" >
    <img src="img/tec.png" alt="tecnico">
  </div>
    <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="login.php">

      <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please login</h2>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Usuario" required="" autofocus="" /><br>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required=""/>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe">Recuérdame
      </label>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>


</div>


<footer>






</footer>



</body>
</html>
```

**cerrarseccion.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
// Elimina la variable email en sesión.
  unset($_SESSION['nombre']);

  // Elimina la sesion.
  session_destroy();

  // Redirecciona a la página de login.
  header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily");
  header("Location: index.html");
?>
```

En la `principal.php` comienzo con este código:

```
<?php
session_start();
// Controlo si el usuario ya está logueado en el sistema.
  if(isset($_SESSION['nombre'])){
    // Le doy la bienvenida al usuario.
    echo 'Bienvenido <strong>'. $_SESSION['mombre'] .'</strong>, <a href="cerrarseccion.php">cerrar sesión</a>';
  }else{
    // Si no está logueado lo redireccion a la página de login.
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily");
    header("Location: index.html");
  }
```

Las demás páginas la conexión es con éste:

```
    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('eeeee','eeeee','eeeeee','eeeeeee');

$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
       if($mysqli->connect_error){

        die('Error en la conexion' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso de [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string) requiere como primer parámetro la conexión si no usas la interfaz OOP.

En tu caso, al usarla, deberías usar el método correcto de `$conn`:

```
<?php
$sql = sprintf(
  "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre ='%s' AND password ='%s'",
  $conn->real_escape_string($nombre),
  $conn->real_escape_string($password)
);
```

Para continuar, el problema por el que entra uses el usuario y contraseña que sea no está relacionado con el uso o no de una función u otra, está relacionado con que únicamente comprueba si la consulta se ejecutó correctamente, no si se encontró un usuario, por lo que hay que obtener el registro con [`mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc):

```
<?php
$resultado = $conn->query($sql);
/* Comprobamos si se ejecutó correctamente la consulta */
if ($resultado !== false) {
  /* Verificando si el usuario existe en la base de datos. */
  $registro = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
  if ($registro !== null) {
    // Guardo en la sesión el email del usuario.
    $_SESSION['nombre'] = $registro['nombre'];
    // Redirecciono al usuario a la página principal del sitio.
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily");
    header("Location: principal.php");
  } else {
    echo 'El usuario o password es incorrecto, <a href="index.html">vuelva a intentarlo</a>.<br/>';
  }
} else {
  die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars($conn->error));
}
```

Al obtener el registro valdrá `null` si no se encontró la coincidencia y en caso de encontrarla el dato del nombre estará en `$registro['nombre']`.

Comment: te amo amigo!!!!!ME FUNCIONO PERFECTO

Comment: Me alegra haber sido de ayuda :)

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta para dar por solucionado el problema.

Comment: oSCAR UNA CONSUTA MAS  EN ESTA LINEA ESTARIA BIEN HECHA PARA QUE ME SALGA EL NOMBRE DEL USUARIO EL CONCADENAMIENTO.......... echo 'Bienvenido <strong>'. $_SESSION['mombre'] .'</strong>, <a href="cerrarseccion.php">cerrar sesión</a>';

Comment: No te recomiendo hacerlo así. Deberías usar `htmlspecialchars()` para escapar todo lo que vayas a enviar al navegador de la siguiente manera: `echo 'Bienvenido <strong>' . htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['nombre']) . '</strong>, <a href="cerrarseccion.php">cerrar sesión</a>';`. Por cierto, cuidado con el índice. Has puesto por error `mombre` en vez de `nombre`.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que validar que el resultado devuelve al menos una fila:

```
// Verificando si el usuario existe en la base de datos.    
if ($resultado && $resultado->num_rows == 1) {
```